# java.util.enumeration equivalent in swift

Tags: java, swift

I have a piece of code in java that i want to convert to swift but can't find a swift equivalent to java's Enumeration interface, any help will be highly appreciated.

### Java `Enumeration`

In Java, `Enumeration` is a class that enables access to a sequence of elements one at a time. Calling `hasMoreElements()` returns a bool indicating whether there is another element, and `nextElement()` moves on to the next item in the sequence and returns it.

### My Java Code

```
import java.util.Enumeration;

private Hashtable<String, Marker> mMarkers;
final Enumeration<String> refs = mMarkers.keys();
    while (refs.hasMoreElements()) {
        final String ref = refs.nextElement();
    }
```

### Question

Does Swift contain an equivalent object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Swift contains an equivalent, but in true Swift fashion, the core functionality takes the form of a Protocol defined in the Swift Standard Library, which is then implemented by other protocols and objects in the standard library.

[This Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/iteratorprotocol) gives you everything you need to know.

Basically, `IteratorProtocol` defines an interface very similar to Java's `Enumeration`. You can then get a special iterator object out of a collection and use it in much the same way.

### Sample

(No import necessary)

```
private var mMarkers: Dictionary<String, Marker>
let refsIterator = mMarkers.keys.makeIterator()
while let ref = refsIterator.next() {
    // do something with ref
}
```

Most of the time, however, unless you need high customization you can just use a for-in loop:

```
private var mMarkers: Dictionary<String, Marker>
for ref in mMarkers.keys {
    // do something with ref
}
```

### Difference Between Java and Swift Implementation

Whether we use Java or Swift, it is important to ensure that a next value exists before we try to do something with that value.

In the case of Java's `Enumerator`, the developer is expected to call `hasMoreElements()` before each call to `next()`, in order to ensure that `next()` will not be trying to access a value that does not exist. So basically, `hasMoreElements()` performs the safety check and `next()` simply attempts to give you the next value. If a "next value" does not exist, Java throws an exception from `next()`.

Swift handles things a bit differently. The safety check is instead done in `next()`, the same function that also returns a value if it exists. So if the safety check fails, `nil` is returned; otherwise, the next value is fetched and returned. Because `next()` returns `Element?` ('Optional') rather than `Element`, we can use `while let` on the returned value. `while let` creates a condition that is only true if `next()` is not `nil`. In addition, when this condition is satisfied, the returned value is automatically added to a constant with a non-Optional type that may be used in the scope of the loop.

This means that in Swift, you could theoretically keep calling `next()` as many times as you want after the sequence has been exhausted, but you will just keep getting `nil` back. Swift largely prefers returning optionals in places like this rather than throwing errors, which are usually reserved for things going wrong. In fact, it wasn't until Swift 2.0 that errors could even be thrown and caught in Swift.

Comment: Might be worth noting some differences between Javas `Enumeration` and Swift:s iterators(/sequences). The former will throw an exception if we try to access a `nextElement()` when one does not exist, and depends solely on using the explicit `hasMoreElements()` method to assert that this is not the case. Whereas in the case of Swift, using the optional (possibly `nil`) return of `next()`, we might even iterate over an "infinite" sequence, only knowing on a per-consumed-element basis that there was indeed a `next()` element in the sequence we're iterating over.